# I still can't understand Optionals

Tags: php, ios, swift

I'm new to the **Swift language** and until this point i only worked in **web development.**

I tried to grasp the idea of optionals, but every time *they* present some situation where to use it, I still can't understand why they do so (or I might have a little idea, but still not sure.)

I read several articles about this and maybe I just got too confused about it along the way and got lost.

So let's present some examples. Let's say I have a registration form with a **textfield** for an e-mail. After the form is sent, in PHP I could do something like:

```
$mail = $_POST['mail'];

if($mail == "") { 
    echo "ERROR: The E-mail is empty";
} else {
    // Do something more
}
```

If the textfield is empty, the value of $_POST['mail'] is an empty string. I can work with that and check if it is empty or not.

Now, if I understand correctly, in swift the value of that textfield wouldn't be an empty string, but actually a nil, right? Is this that kind of a difference why we need optionals? Because in comparison to PHP, in Swift I have to declare the type of that information each time and it doesn't know if that textfield passes strings or numbers?

Let's talk about another example. Lot of people in **swift** just declare a string as an optional, even if they put a value in it, like so:

```
let name:String? = "Gabriel"
```

If it already has a value, why make it an optional then? For me, it is just a normal constant with a value and I don't see the point of wrapping it into an optional.

**If I don't know the name at the declaration, why can't i just type this?**

```
let name:String = ""
```

and after that, I can use an if statement to check if it is empty or not

```
if name == "" {
  print("ERROR: name is empty")
} else {
  //Do something else
}
```

Did I get the idea with the textfield right or not?
Is there something I'm missing?

Thank You for any help!

**EDIT (What got me understanding the concept):**

What I got confused about the most was the simple fact, that for example a **String can store only "text"** and that if nil was something, it wouldn't be of type String, so therefore **it couldn't be "stored" inside String of course**.

Just in the same way, as I can't store text into an Integer — **I can't "store" nil into a String.**

But with Optional String I can use this **"wrapper"** that actually **CAN** "store" both types: string or nil. And that is what distinguish regular String from Optional String. It is this "wrapper" that has the ability to "hold" both these types until I need to use the actual value. (Now of course I understand, that nil is actually an absence of any value. I just used it in this way to illustrate the point)

Thank You everyone for Your help!

Comment: optional mean the value can be `nil` at some point, even if you give it value at declared, and when read you have to check either if its nil or have value, non-optional mean it can never be `nil`, if nil and read it will crash

Comment: But checking for the nil would be the same problem as checking for an empty value. To check if string is empty, or Int == 0, in the same way I could check if something == nil and i wouldn't need optionals for that, just an if statement.

Comment: Its different, 0 is not nil, 0 mean a value of 0, nil mean it doesnt have any value at all in physical memory, just an empty pointer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine you ordered a playstation from ebay. The first thing you see is not the playstation, but a box. So, in this instance, the box is an optional. Let's write it down.

```
var playstation: Playstation?
```

The box can of course be empty. In order to use the playstation, we need to open the box. We have several ways to do that.

The safe way:

```
if let ps = playstation {
  // if the box is not empty, and the PS is there
  ps.play()
} else {
  print("The box was empty :(")
}
```

The other way:

```
playstation?.play()
```

In this other scenario, we're only calling the play() method if the contents of playstation box are not empty. Downside is that you cannot display an error in case it fails.

What if you promised your friend that you'll play together on your playstation that will be here today. You're giving a guarantee that the playstation will be in the box. That's when you use this:

```
playstation!.play()
```

Problem with this approach, in actual programs, is that your app will crash if the contents of the optional are empty. Use "!" only if you can guarantee that it will not be empty (i.e. you assigned a value to the variable right before this)

So, to conclude, optionals are variables whose value can be either a specific type (i.e. String) or **nil**. You cannot assign **nil** to strongly typed variables.

```
var a: String?
var b: String

a = nil // this is ok
b = nil // this will not compile
```

Comment: Actually the last sentence might finally get sense to me.
The problem is that Strings only store strings, Integers only store numbers. But an optional string can "store" both String and Nil (in a way).

Because just as I can't declare
let number:Int = "String", I can't have no value in a variable.

So that is the case why i need the Type optional, to be prepared that I might not get type String, but also a "type" nil (if it was a type)

Comment: If you need more details on what a nil is, you can check this article. http://nshipster.com/swift-literal-convertible/

Comment: So does that mean I understood it correctly? That I've been missing the "simple" point the whole time? That it's just that String can handle only "text", but Optional String can handle both "Text" and Nil if necessary?

Comment: Yes, but you need to unwrap the optional to use the text, or the value will be  Optional("your text") when you print it out. See the 3 examples above on how to unwrap.

Comment: Yes, I understand the wrapping. I think the main confusion for me was the fact, that I can't put nil inside String, just text. And that if i tried to put nil in there, it would crash. But Optional String gives me this wrapper for both String or Nill. Which wouldn't be possible with normal string. And of course that in order to use this value at the end, I must unwrap it (best with optional binding)

Answer (score 2):

Think of optionals like this :

**An optional is a variable which can be empty something in the future or even now.**

Making a variable an optional means it is **wrapped as an enum.**

Suppose there is a variable : `var x : Int?`, this means a variable named x of type Int, is not yet initialised and an optional.

This typically can be represented in layman terms as

```
Enum x(optional) // name of the variable{
 case T: // some value
 case nil: // no value
}
```

So when we assign a variable we can just assign it normally, but the value is stored in the **case T of the optional enum variable of x**.

```
x = 10 // 
enum x(optional){
     case T = 10
     case nil 
 }
```

When we want to use it(get the value) **we use a (?) or an (!)**

These can be farther explained as

`print(x?)` // **If there is any value inside of x, give it to me(in this case give me the value of x's case of T)**

`print(x!)` // **I dont care if there is any value inside of x or not, just give it to me anyway.**

Hence if x has no value then printing (x!) will produce a crash, as x does not have a value inside of it.

`?` - **safely unwrapping the optional**

`!` - **force unwrapping the optional**

P.S - I know there are certain things I missed but this is the jist of Optional is this is meant only for explanatory purpose. Once you grasp this concept you can farther check out more documents on Apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional)

Answer (score 0):

Effectively,

```
let name:String? = "Gabriel"
```

is not very useful.
But

```
var name:String? = "Gabriel"
```

does make sense, as you can further on set to nil.

Optionals are very useful for returning value from function.
Consider a func that returns an Int.

If the value is not found, you could return a number (like very large negative) to notify value was not found. But there is a risk some day that the func does return this value (even unlikely).
Returning a nil let the function make it clear it did not find the value.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of optionals is that they are a type just like String, or an Int, or a Double.  Optionals have associated values so an String? is an optional with a String associated to it.  The optional can either contain a value which is a string, even an empty string or nothing at all, which to me is null.  Check out the Stanford U IOS course on iTunes.  Optionals are explained much better then I am able to.